# Force ClickOnce setup to specific path C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce install with visual studio for my C# console application.
I need to install the application at a same path for all of my users, because of that the regular install path is not good for me.
How can i change the installation path?

Comment: you can't thats how click once works. it does it all with temp files and such.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with ClickOnce. All applications are installed per user in the users application cache.

Comment: is it possible to run code during the installation? like changing configuration file?